# PHP multiple fields contact form issue

Tags: php, contact-form

I've got a problem with a PHP contact form (yes, classic issue I know).

I'm pretty new in PHP and I don't find what is broken in my code.

Here is the PHP:

```html
<?php

// Email address verification
function isEmail($email) {
  return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

if($_POST) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the message
    $emailTo = 'contact@must-assurances.com';

    $clientEmail = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
    $name = addslashes(trim($_POST['name']));
    $entreprise = addslashes(trim($_POST['entreprise']));
    $message = addslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    $antispam = addslashes(trim($_POST['antispam']));
    $jesuis = addslashes(trim($_POST['jesuis']));
    $tel = addslashes(trim($_POST['tel']));
    $siren = addslashes(trim($_POST['siren']));

    $array = array('emailMessage' => '', 'entrepriseMessage' => '', 'messageMessage' => '', 'antispamMessage' => '', 'jesuisMessage' =>'', 'nameMessage' =>'', 'telMessage' =>'', 'sirenMessage' =>'' );

    if($siren == '') {
        $array['sirenMessage'] = 'SIREN/SIRET invalide';
    } 
    if(!isEmail($clientEmail)) {
        $array['emailMessage'] = 'Email invalide';
    }
    if($name == '') {
        $array['nameMessage'] = 'Nom manquant';
    }    
    if($entreprise == '') {
        $array['entrepriseMessage'] = 'Entreprise manquante';
    }
    if($tel == '') {
        $array['telMessage'] = 'Numéro de téléphone manquant';
    }
    if($siren == '') {
        $array['sirenMessage'] = 'SIREN/SIRET invalide';
    }
    if($message == '') {
        $array['messageMessage'] = 'Message manquant';
    }
    if($antispam != '12') {
      $array['antispamMessage'] = 'Mauvaise réponse';
    }
    if($jesuis == '') {
        $array['jesuisMessage'] = 'Merci de préciser si vous êtes une entreprise, un courtier, un investisseur, un professionnel ou autre';
    }
    if(isEmail($clientEmail) && $entreprise != '' && $message != '' && $antispam == '12' && $jesuis != '' && $name !='' && $tel !='' && $siren!='') {
        // Send email
    $message = "Je suis un(e) ".$jesuis."\n \n ".$message."\n \n ".$name."\n \n ".$tel."\n \n ".$entreprise."\n \n ".$siren;    
    $headers = "From: " . $clientEmail . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail . 
    $headers = array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    mail($emailTo, $entreprise . " (Formulaire inscription distributeur MUST Assurances)", $message, $headers);
    }        
    echo json_encode($array);
}

?>
```

And here the HTML snippet:

```html
<form role="form" action="contact-mia.php" method="post" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
                                 <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                    <label for="name">Votre nom :</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Votre nom..." class="contact-name form-control" id="name">
                                  </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                  <label for="email">Votre adresse e-mail :</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email..." class="contact-email form-control" id="email">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                    <label for="name">Votre numéro de téléphone :</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="tel" placeholder="Numéro de téléphone..." class="contact-tel form-control" id="tel">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                    <label for="entreprise">Entreprise :</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="entreprise" placeholder="Entreprise..." class="contact-entreprise form-control" id="entreprise">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                        <label for="jesuis">Je suis : </label>
                                        <select class="form-control" name="jesuis" id="jesuis">
                                          <option value="">Selectionnez...</option>
                                          <option value="entreprise">Une entreprise</option>
                                          <option value="courtier">Un courtier</option>
                                          <option value="investisseur">Un investisseur</option>
                                          <option value="professionnel">Un professionnel</option>
                                          <option value="autre">Autre</option>
                                        </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="entreprise">Numéro de SIREN/SIRET :</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="siren" placeholder="SIREN/SIRET..." class="contact-siren form-control" id="siren">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                    <label for="message">Message :</label>
                                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message..." class="contact-message form-control" id="message"></textarea>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                    <label for="antispam">Question Antispam : 7 + 5 = ?</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="antispam" placeholder="Votre réponse..." class="contact-antispam form-control" id="antispam">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 form-group centered">
                                  <button type="submit" class="btn">Envoyer</button>
                                  </div>  
                              </form>
```

Another issue about my $message syntax, here is the code:

```html
$message = "Je suis un(e) ".$jesuis.'<br />'"Nom : ".$name.'<br />'"Telephone : ".$tel.'<br />'"SIREN : ".$siren.'<br />'"Entreprise : ".$entreprise.'<br />' "Message : ".$message;
```

Probably something wrong with the ' and " ?

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you also explain what the problem is?

Comment: whats the problem ?

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: Hi,Of course i didnt explain the whole problem. The thing is that nothing happens. The contact form doesnt trigger... You can see a test link here : http://must-conseil.com/inscription

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP side has an error on the IF statement:

*Take a further look at the lines containing: `$headers`*

**Your code:**

```
if(isEmail($clientEmail) && $entreprise != '' && $message != '' && $antispam == '12' && $jesuis != '' && $name !='' && $tel !='' && $siren!='') {
    // Send email
    $message = "Je suis un(e) ".$jesuis."\n \n ".$message."\n \n ".$name."\n \n ".$tel."\n \n ".$entreprise."\n \n ".$siren;    
    $headers = "From: " . $clientEmail . " <" . $clientEmail . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail . 
    $headers = array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    mail($emailTo, $entreprise . " (Formulaire inscription distributeur MUST Assurances)", $message, $headers);
}
```

**Corrected Code:**

```
if(isEmail($clientEmail) && $entreprise != '' && $message != '' && $antispam == '12' && $jesuis != '' && $name !='' && $tel !='' && $siren!='') {
    // Send email
    $message = "Je suis un(e) ".$jesuis."\n \n ".$message."\n \n ".$name."\n \n ".$tel."\n \n ".$entreprise."\n \n ".$siren;    
    $headers = "From: " . $clientEmail . " <" . $clientEmail . ">\r\n";
    $headers.= "Reply-To: " . $clientEmail . "\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    // Wrap mail function in if statement to check if it worked
    if (@mail($emailTo, $entreprise . " (Formulaire inscription distributeur MUST Assurances)", $message, $headers)) {
        echo 'Successfully sent email';
    } else {
        echo 'Failed to send';
    }
}
```

To help debug your code ensure your PHP errors are enabled, you can do this at the top of your PHP code using the following:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Comment: Thanks Danny, I've changed my code with yours, probably better but the contact form still doesnt trigger

Comment: Wrap your mail() function into an if statement to see if your mail function is working (see corrected code as ive updated it). Ensure your using some form of developer tools to watch over your network activity to see the response you get back.

Comment: Again, thanks Danny ! The contact form works fine now ;)

Comment: Brilliant! no problem, glad to of helped.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a new issue about my $message syntax.

Here is the code :

```html
$message = "Je suis un(e) ".$jesuis.'<br />'"Nom : ".$name.'<br />'"Telephone : ".$tel.'<br />'"SIREN : ".$siren.'<br />'"Entreprise : ".$entreprise.'<br />' "Message : ".$message;
```

Probably something about the ' or " ?